# GWT: session invalidate on window close works in development mode but not on actual server

Tags: gwt

I am using this code to invalidate user session on browser close .

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {
    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
        logOut();    
    }         
});
```

logOut method is just calling the RPC and making session invalidate .. 
as soon i close the browser , it closes and after that the call made to server and reaches to server which invalidate the session successfully.

But when i put my application on Tomcat or any web hosting .. This functionality stops working ..

any idea ..what could be the solution

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in the console ? Is that RPC call is working when you run it in the tomcat ?

Comment: dont see any javascript error, the call couldnt reach to server , before that the browser get closed and connection lost message appear on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your problem is, that the browser is closed before the rcp call had a chance to send the underlying XMLHTTPRequest to the server.

I would give the WindowClosingHandler a chance:

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
    logOut();
  }
});
```

If this does not work, try to add a native javascript function that is called by the onBeforeUnload event and use JSNI to call your logOut() method.